# Where can I find airport diagrams for the Philippines?

Tags: airport, aeronautical-charts, philippines

I would like to have airport map, just like the one that pilots can see when they are taxiing. Is it possible to get such a map, even if you are not a pilot? Perhaps there are applications which a person can use to simulate taxiing on specific runways?

I am interested in Manila airport (MNL) and Mactan-Cebu airport (CEB).

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: resource location is off-topic as defined by the (help center)[/help/on-topic]. You may rephrase your question such that it ask for what you are looking for, the answer being likely to give you links to relevant resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to type the IATA code into Google along with "airport charts". The PDF you are looking for will be high in the search results. Here are the diagrams for Manila and Cebu.

[image: MNL Diagream]

[image: CEB Diagram]

Comment: Is there also some kind of application where you can simulate taxiing on selected airport?

Comment: www.proflightsimulator.com